# Get user attributes AWS Amplify iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm building an iOS app with the SDK Amplify so I have my users registered on AWS.

I already have my sign in/sign up flow working but the problem is that with the newest version of the SDK I have absolutely no idea of how can I get attributes of a registered user like his family name, email address etc...

With this new SDK everything seems to work around the `AWSMobileClient`class but I see nothing from this class that can help me to get what I want.

The [official documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start?ref=amplify-iOS-btn) is anemic and doesn't cover or even point to my use case.

If somebody can give me some hint or even some good ressources I'll be very thankful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi YoanGJ and future guests,

Based on your comment you were looking for some sample code.

```
    AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().getUserAttributes { (attributes, error) in
            if let attributes = attributes {
                XCTAssertTrue(attributes.count == 3, "Expected 3 attributes for user.")
                XCTAssertTrue(attributes["email_verified"] == "false", "Email should not be verified.")
            }else if let error = error {
                XCTFail("Received un-expected error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            getAttrExpectation.fulfill()
}
```

This excerpt shows how you could call `getUserAttributes` and it comes from the integration tests found [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSAuthSDK/Tests/AWSMobileClientTests/AWSMobileClientTests.swift#L200).

Comment: Thanks for this example and this ressource

Comment: Great @donkon Thanks for this snippet. 

Answer (score 2):

The method was missing from the initial release and has since been added. You can use the getUserAttributes with the following API in the latest SDK version `2.8.x`:

```
public func getUserAttributes(completionHandler: @escaping (([String: String]?, Error?) -> Void))
```

You can find the source code here:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSAuthSDK/Sources/AWSMobileClient/AWSMobileClientExtensions.swift#L532

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: You're right, my pods were not updated. But with the 2.8.x version, when I try to call `getUserAttributes` the placeholder asks me to provide an instance of AWSMobileClient but no mention of the `completionHandler`... Do you have some exemples of implementation please?

Answer (score 0):

**For a note:**

Make sure you did configure attribute read and write permission accordingly in your ***Cognito user pool App client*** to access your user attributes using `getUserAttributes`.

To configure attributes read and write permissions in user pool,

> User pool -> General settings -> App clients -> Choose your app client
>   -> Show details -> Set attribute read and write permissions

[image]

Thanks!